# Python でログを CSV ファイルとして出力したい

Tags: python, csv

以下ログをcsvに転記する方法を探しています。
各リストの空白スペースを1に統一するところまでは出来たのですが、
csvに転記するところで躓いております。
何か良案がありましたらご教示頂けると助かります。

```
data_list=
['12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty\n', '12:10:01 AM   9913200   6352688     39.06    575700   5111548   5230536     21.22    860532   4858452        32\n', '12:20:01 AM   9912084   6353804     39.06    575736   5111588   5230272     21.21    860552   4858432        12\n', ]

for i in range(len(datalist)): 
      new_data = [" ".join(datalist[i].split(''))] 

print(new_data)

#出力結果#
['12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused %memused kbbuffers kbcached kbcommit %commit kbactive kbinact kbdirty']
['12:10:01 AM 9913200 6352688 39.06 575700 5111548 5230536 21.22 860532 4858452 32']
['12:20:01 AM 9912084 6353804 39.06 575736 5111588 5230272 21.21 860552 4858432 12']
```

Comment: Excelファイル(拡張子が`.xlsx`等)ですか？ CSV(拡張子が`.csv`)では無く？ その場合はだいたいその機能を持ったライブラリ/モジュールが必要になりますよ。色々あるので何を使いたいかを決めた方が良いでしょう。ちなみにどれが良いか？という質問はこのサイトではあまり歓迎されない「お買い物リスト質問」になるので避けましょう。

Comment: ご回答、ご教示ありがとうございます。また、説明不足もうしわけございません。csvとなります。質問内容訂正いたしました。

Comment: 出力結果の部分は「実際の出力結果」ですか？それとも「期待する出力結果」のどちらでしょうか？ / "躓いている" の説明をもう少し詳しく書いておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandasあるいはopenpyxlを調べてみてください。

ひとまず、目的の結果と思われるものが以下のソースコードで実現できたと思います。
最初の時刻ヘッダ部分をtimeとmeridianに置き換えています。

ソースコード

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

log_list = [
    r'12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused %memused kbbuffers kbcached kbcommit %commit kbactive kbinact kbdirty',
    r'12:10:01 AM 9913200 6352688 39.06 575700 5111548 5230536 21.22 860532 4858452 32',
    r'12:20:01 AM 9912084 6353804 39.06 575736 5111588 5230272 21.21 860552 4858432 12',
]

print(log_list)

heading = log_list[0]
logdata = log_list[1:]

headings = heading.split()
headings[0] = 'time'
headings[1] = 'meridian'


def export_excel():
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    if wb.sheetnames:
        for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
            wb.remove(wb[sheet_name])
    ws = wb.create_sheet(title="log")

    for i, head in enumerate(headings):
        cell = ws.cell(1, i+1)
        cell.value = head

    for i, log_line in enumerate(logdata):
        log = log_line.split()
        for j, c in enumerate(log):
            cell = ws.cell(i+2, j+1)
            cell.value = c

    wb.save("log.xlsx")

    wb.close()


def export_csv():
    data_list = [
        headings,
    ]
    for log_line in logdata:
        log = log_line.split()
        data_list.append(log)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    df.to_csv('log.csv', header=False, index=False)
    print(df)


export_excel()
export_csv()
```

Comment: ありがとうございました！目的の内容実現できました

pandasあるいはopenpyxlを調べてみてください。
＞承知しました

Answer (score 1):

`data_list`を加工せずに直接DataFrameに変換し、[`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)で列を分割する方法もあります。

**サンプルコード**

```
import pandas as pd

data_list = ['12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty\n', '12:10:01 AM   9913200   6352688     39.06    575700   5111548   5230536     21.22    860532   4858452        32\n', '12:20:01 AM   9912084   6353804     39.06    575736   5111588   5230272     21.21    860552   4858432        12\n', ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df = df[0].str.split(expand=True)
df.to_csv("sample.csv", header=False, index=False)
```

**sample.csv**

```
12:00:01,AM,kbmemfree,kbmemused,%memused,kbbuffers,kbcached,kbcommit,%commit,kbactive,kbinact,kbdirty
12:10:01,AM,9913200,6352688,39.06,575700,5111548,5230536,21.22,860532,4858452,32
12:20:01,AM,9912084,6353804,39.06,575736,5111588,5230272,21.21,860552,4858432,12
```

Comment: おお、このようなシンプルなコードでも実現できるのですね！
ご教示ありがとうございます。とても勉強になります

Answer (score 1):

既に解決しているようですが、文字列をcsvに書き出すだけならpandasを使うよりも標準の`csv`モジュールを使ったほうが圧倒的に簡単ですし処理も速いです。`str.split('')`でいわゆる「リストのリスト」にできたのなら、`writetows()`メソッドを使ってそれをそのままcsvファイルとして書き出すことができます。

```py
import csv

data_list = [
    "12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty\n",
    "12:10:01 AM   9913200   6352688     39.06    575700   5111548   5230536     21.22    860532   4858452        32\n",
    "12:20:01 AM   9912084   6353804     39.06    575736   5111588   5230272     21.21    860552   4858432        12\n",
]

with open("log.csv", mode="w", newline="") as fw:
    csv.writer(fw).writerows(map(lambda s: s.split(), data_list))
```

参考：
[csv --- CSV ファイルの読み書き — Python 3.10.4 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html)
[PythonでCSVファイルを読み込み・書き込み（入力・出力） | note.nkmk.me](https://note.nkmk.me/python-csv-reader-writer/)

Comment: ご教示頂きありがとうございます！最終的にtkinterでアプリケーションにして配布予定だったので、csvモジュールで目的が達成できるのはかなり助かります！
また、参照さきについても確認させて頂きます